# Narrow down literal unions based on previously used values

Tags: typescript

The scenario is the following:

```
type Option = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd'

type Question = {
  message: string;
  options: Option[];
  default: Option // here's the issue
}
```

I want the `default` prop to be the one of the options used inside `question.options`. For example:

```
const q1: Question = {
  message: 'first question',
  options: ['a', 'b'],
  default: 'a'
}

const q2: Question = {
  message: 'second question',
  options: ['c', 'd'],
  default: 'a' // I want this to give an error because 'a' is not in 'c' | 'd'
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done just by using `Question`; however, it will be a complex type that will cause a horrible time for the compiler since it grows at the speed of power of two, and if you have more options (more than 10), the compiler will reach its limits and won't compile.

Instead, I would suggest adjusting `Question` to accept the `Option[]` as a generic parameter and assign the type of the elements of that generic parameter to `default`:

```
type Question<T extends Option[]> = {
  message: string;
  options: T;
  default: T[number];
};
```

Lastly, we will need a generic function that would create a question for us:

```
const createQuestion = <T extends Option[]>(question: Question<T>) => question;
```

Usage:

```
const q1 = createQuestion({
  message: "first question",
  options: ["a", "b"],
  default: "a",
});

const q2 = createQuestion({
  message: "second question",
  options: ["c", "d"],
  default: "a", // Expected error
});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7KBeKAiAhlqAPtgEb5FYDGZ2AJlgNwCwAUC6JFAIoCuEAzolQAeACpQIAD2AQUNPrHjIUAbQC6APgxQA3iyhQAtvz44A5hABcUAQCcEKU02b6ki1Hysin+mhABmONwANsCeyijcBsQQNqpOAL5OLBTuwFAUNhA40jz8gmiYouJSMnIK+WrqABQAjrwCSla5DcIi6gCUGJp1eUpJzCkoAlA1AIxaGVk59flVus6GxmaW2H4INsM9LShYADR6UK75HlDKuHskWKr7C74BwaHYeDfx7f2DmwBME5nZEM2zeb6Ix8EzmKxYPgQQY0EYzJR7A5HJQnM5UXa0K43Hz+QIhCHPKAAeiJUAAohJIBRpLCYjYkDYWK8nEA)

Comment: Interesting. It does what I want, but I wasn't expecting a function was needed for this. Especially not the identity function. I was expecting some obscure `infer` or something like that